# How to use prepared statement efficiently using datastax java driver in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax-java-driver

I need to query one of the tables in Cassandra using Datastax Java driver. Below is the code I have which works fine -

```
public class TestCassandra {

        private Session session = null;
        private Cluster cluster = null;

        private static class ConnectionHolder {
            static final TestCassandra connection = new TestCassandra();
        }

        public static TestCassandra getInstance() {
            return ConnectionHolder.connection;
        }

        private TestCassandra() {
            Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
            builder.addContactPoints("127.0.0.1");

            PoolingOptions opts = new PoolingOptions();
            opts.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, opts.getCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL));

            cluster = builder.withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE).withPoolingOptions(opts)
                    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("DC2")))
                    .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
                    .build();
            session = cluster.connect();
        }

    private Set<String> getRandomUsers() {
        Set<String> userList = new HashSet<String>();

        for (int table = 0; table < 14; table++) {
            String sql = "select * from testkeyspace.test_table_" + table + ";";

            try {
                SimpleStatement query = new SimpleStatement(sql);
                query.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
                ResultSet res = session.execute(query);

                Iterator<Row> rows = res.iterator();
                while (rows.hasNext()) {
                    Row r = rows.next();

                    String user_id = r.getString("user_id");
                    userList.add(user_id);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error= " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }

        return userList;
    }
}
```

I am using above class like this in my main application -

```
TestCassandra.getInstance().getRandomUsers();
```

Is there any way I can use `PreparedStatement` in `getRandomUsers` efficiently? I guess I need to make sure that I am creating `PreparedStatement` only once instead of creating it multiple times. What is the best design for that in my current architecture and how can I use it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a cache (this is a fairly basic example to give you an idea) of the statements you need. Lets start by creating the class that will be used as a cache.

```
private class StatementCache {
    Map<String, PreparedStatement> statementCache = new HashMap<>();
    public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
        PreparedStatement ps = statementCache.get(cql);
        // no statement cached, create one and cache it now.
        if (ps == null) {
            ps = session.prepare(cql);
            statementCache.put(cql, ps);
        }
        return ps.bind();
    }
}
```

Then add an instance to your singleton:

```
public class TestCassandra {
    private Session session = null;
    private Cluster cluster = null;
    private StatementCache psCache = new StatementCache();
    // rest of class...
```

And finally use the cache from your function:

```
private Set<String> getRandomUsers(String cql) {
// lots of code.    
        try {
            SimpleStatement query = new SimpleStatement(cql);
            query.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
            // abstract the handling of the cache to it's own class.
            // this will need some work to make sure it's thread safe
            // as currently it's not.
            ResultSet res = session.execute(psCache.getStatement(cql));
```

Comment: This is awesome. I understood now what we need to do so basically we need to make a singleton thread safe class in which we need to populate all the new statements in a cache and then use those statements from the getter. Right?

Comment: @david Actually, I'd have a cache per n threads (you need to work out when the map's get becomes too expensive thus meaning a new shared cache is required) Try something like 1 cache per 5 threads. Possibly even each thread should have it's own ps cache (based on how many statements are in there, the more statements, the fewer caches you need).

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment, cache per n threads? How we can do that?

Comment: Examples work best when confusion becomes a problem. Say you have 2000 threads doing the SELECTs. This means you will be sharing 1 cache with 2000 threads. That is a bad idea performance-wise. Instead for every n threads, let's be concrete and say every 20 threads you share a cache. This means you will have 2000 / 20 = 100 prepared statement caches. How do you do that? You'll need mapping between the set of threads and their respective caches. I'll leave the implementation to you. Also note that these numbers are random, load tests will be required to find the optimum proportion of caches.

Comment: @LyubenTodorov but how to do that when these threads are servlet requests?

Comment: What will be the benefit of having `cache per n threads`? Why not just have a singleton class for this and use it?

Comment: @lining it's a cache instance that is added to the singleton thus it's not a cache per n threads but exactly a singleton cache. This was written quickly for demo purposes, a properly constructed singleton cache might be necessary in production apps.

Comment: The cache for thread isn't necessary. "You should prepare only once, and cache the PreparedStatement in your application (it is thread-safe). If you call prepare multiple times with the same query string, the driver will log a warning." https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/manual/statements/prepared/

Answer (score 1):

My implementation is more or less the same as the ones shared above, but with performance checks and implementations to take care of race conditions.See inline comments on code on my thought process.

```
 import com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement;
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
 import nl.ing.creditcards.commons.activity.ActivityException;

 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class StatementCache {

/* prevent cache incoherence issues*/
private static volatile StatementCache sCacheInstance;
private static final Map<String, PreparedStatement> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static final String NOT_PERMITTED = "Operation not permitted";

private StatementCache() {
    /*Prevent access through reflection api.*/
    if (sCacheInstance != null) {
        throw new ActivityException(NOT_PERMITTED, "Use getInstance() to retrieve the instance of this class");
    }
}

/**
 * Double check locking pattern usage for singleton classes
 *
 * @return
 */
public static StatementCache getInstance() {
    if (sCacheInstance == null) { //Check for the first time
        synchronized (StatementCache.class) { // second check in order to keep the operation atomic
            if (sCacheInstance == null) sCacheInstance = new StatementCache();
        }
    }
    return sCacheInstance;
}

/**
 * If {@link StatementCache#getStatement#prepared_statement} is already present in cache,
 * then we don't have to synchronize and make threads wait, otherwise, we synchronize the caching bit.
 *
 * @param session
 * @param cql
 * @return
 */
public PreparedStatement getStatement(Session session, String cql) {
    PreparedStatement prepared_statement = holder.get(cql);
    if (prepared_statement == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            prepared_statement = holder.get(cql);
            if (prepared_statement == null) {
                prepared_statement = session.prepare(cql);
                holder.put(cql, prepared_statement);
            }
        }
    }
    return prepared_statement;
  }
}
```

Using this cache singleton class would be as simple as :

```
public class CacheConsumer{

    private static Session session;

    CacheConsumer(Session session){
     this.session=session;
   }

    public void someMethod(){
      String cqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE";
      PreparedStatement statement= 
       StatementCache.getInstance().getStatement(session,cqlstatement);
         // You can now use the prepared statement however you wish.
   }
}
```

Pretty simple ;)